# T-SQL : Where clause using OR Conditions and null checking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a stored procedure where I pass in three post codes (or T-SQL regex of postcodes)

```
@postCode nvarchar(50) null,
@postCode2 nvarchar(50) null,
@postCode3 nvarchar(50) null,
```

In my where clause I need to search for any of the post codes entered, but if a null value is passed, ignore the parameter.

If I use ANDs like below no rows are returned as it's looking a record that matches two different postcodes

```
WHERE ((@postCode IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode)
  AND (@postCode2 IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode2) 
  AND (@postCode3 IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode3))
```

And if I use ORs then as soon as one of the parameters is null it will return any postcode in the table

```
WHERE ((@postCode IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE  @postCode)
   OR (@postCode2 IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode2) 
   OR (@postCode3 IS NULL OR CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode3))
```

I have to account for all three parameters being null

How do I ignore the condition when a parameter is null, but still use an OR condition when a value is supplied?

Comment: Add some sample data.  Your method for accepting either a match or a null parameter look correct to me.

Comment: Are these UK postcodes? If so `varchar(10)` would cover all valid codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `IS NULL` clauses at all:

```sql
WHERE (CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode
   OR  CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode2
   OR  CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode3)
```

Though, in truth, it seems like what you would be better off with is a Table Type Parameter. Then you can pass 0+ values for the postcodes (though passing 0 rows would result in no results), and could do a simple `EXISTS`:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @YourTableParameter YTP
              WHERE CPC.CompPostCode LIKE YTP.PostCode)
```

---

Answer for moved goal posts:

To cater for all the values of the parameters being `NULL` you need to add an extra `OR`:

```sql
WHERE (CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode
   OR  CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode2
   OR  CompPostCode.CompPostCode LIKE @postCode3
   OR (@postCode IS NULL AND @postCode2 IS NULL AND @postCode3 IS NULL))
```

With a table type parameter, you would need to add a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```sql
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM @YourTableParameter YTP
               WHERE CPC.CompPostCode LIKE YTP.PostCode)
   OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @YourTableParameter YTP))
```

Now that both of these are a "catch-all"/"Kitchen sink" query, I also **strongly** suggest you add `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause of your query if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, However what wasn't mentioned in the post is that all of the parameters may be null (I've just updated the question) If this is the case the postcode filtering should be ignored entirely.  I don't think either of the above account for that?

Comment: How can I cater for a requirement that isn't in the post, @RichardWatts ..?

Comment: I understand, my mistake. I've updated the post

Comment: I've updated the answer for the new goalposts, @RichardWatts , however, in the future please make sure you outline the requirements properly when you post the question; moving the goal posts *after* you have an received answer that invalidates said answer is very frowned upon; really you should be posting a new question.